# Uncaught ReferenceError: Papa is not defined

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I am using Papa Parser to parse a CSV using JavaScript. When the function is called I receive the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Papa is not defined."

I have ensured the the papaparse.js is loaded before my own custom logic is loaded and still receive this error.

Here is the function that in my own logic.js file:

```
$('#import-button').click(function(){
    // Valiting the bank and CSV file
    if($('#bank').val() == null) {
        alert("Please select a bank.");
        return;
    }
    if(!$('#inputFileName').val()) {
        alert('Please select a CSV file.');
        return;
    }
    var file = document.getElementById('inputFile');
    Papa.parse(file);
});
```

My HTML document is long so I wont post the whole thing. I am loading the JS at the end of the body element . It looks like:

```
    <script src = './src/js/papaparse.min.js'></script>
    <!-- Lodaing the jQuery library -->
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./src/js/jquery-2.1.4.js');</script>
    <!-- Loading the Bootstrap js -->
    <script src = './src/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src = './src/js/logic.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            // Creates dropdown for accounts
            createSelectAccount('import-account', false);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The location to the papaparse.min.js file is correct, but once i click the "import-button" and the function is called I receive that error.

Any idea what is causing it?

Note - I realize the jQuery library is loaded differently, just trying something out.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery should be first file to import..

```
<script src='./src/js/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>

 <script src = './src/js/papaparse.min.js'></script>
    <!-- Lodaing the jQuery library -->

    <!-- Loading the Bootstrap js -->
    <script src = './src/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src = './src/js/logic.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            // Creates dropdown for accounts
            createSelectAccount('import-account', false);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried that. I moved it below the jQuery but still receive the same error.

Comment: `Papa` does not require `jQuery` so technically `jQuery` could be referenced anywhere

Comment: it generally an order issue of java script files. you may need to include papaparse file just before logic.js file

Comment: It doesn't matter the order since the line is called on a click handler. By the time the user is more than likely to click the element and trigger the handler all the libraries should have been loaded